# Qual a lógica para fazer esse select funcionar?

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para fazer esse select exibir de acordo com o que for selecionado ali dentre as opções 'Mais recentes, Avaliação, Utilidade'?:
[image]

Os mais recentes seria os ultimos comentários adicionado!
O Avaliação seria os comentário que tivessem mais avaliação positiva em estrelas e iria baixando, por exemplo 5, 4, 3 etc...
E o Utilidade seria os comentário com mais like.

Exibição dos comentário normal:

```
$selecionarComentarios = $conexao->prepare("SELECT a.id_mark, a.id_user, a.comment, a.rate, a.id, a.active, b.name, b.avatar FROM tb_comment a, users b WHERE a.id_user=b.id AND a.id_mark = :post_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_pg, $amount_pg");
$selecionarComentarios->bindParam(':post_id',$post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$selecionarComentarios->execute();
```

**Via GET consegui o que eu queria!!**

```
    if (isset($_GET["op_com"]))
{
    $op_com = $_GET["op_com"];
    if($op_com=="recent")
    {
        $select_comment = "SELECT a.id_mark, a.id_user, a.comment, a.rate, a.id, a.active, b.name, b.avatar FROM tb_comment a, users b WHERE a.id_user=b.id AND a.id_mark = :post_id ORDER BY active DESC LIMIT ".$start_pg.", ".$amount_pg."";
    }
    if($op_com=="rating")
    {
        $select_comment = "SELECT a.id_mark, a.id_user, a.comment, a.rate, a.id, a.active, b.name, b.avatar FROM tb_comment a, users b WHERE a.id_user=b.id AND a.id_mark = :post_id ORDER BY rate DESC LIMIT ".$start_pg.", ".$amount_pg."";
    }
    if($op_com=="good")
    {
        $select_comment = "SELECT a.id_mark, a.id_user, a.comment, a.rate, a.id, a.active, a.good, b.name, b.avatar
    FROM tb_comment a, users b
    WHERE a.id_user=b.id AND a.id_mark = :post_id ORDER BY good DESC LIMIT ".$start_pg.", ".$amount_pg."";
    }
}
else
{
    $select_comment = "SELECT a.id_mark, a.id_user, a.comment, a.rate, a.id, a.active, b.name, b.avatar FROM tb_comment a, users b WHERE a.id_user=b.id AND a.id_mark = :post_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start_pg.", ".$amount_pg."";
}
```

Comment: Pode usar Javascript para somente reorganizar os comentários. Fazer uma nova consulta ou uma chamada a um recurso php só para isso, pelo menos na minha opinião é desnecessário. Como não há nenhum código para basear e dar uma resposta, fica aí como comentário uma forma que eu faria :)

Comment: Orde by na consulta?

Comment: Vou postar o código PHP pra exibir aqueles comentário ali.

Comment: @rray Ala postei o SELECT que uso para puxar os comentário atual da foto.

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples: use ajax.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

$(function(){
  var opcoes = $('select[name=select_comentario]');
  opcoes.on('change', function(){
    $.get('sua_pagina_de_consulta.php', { ordenar: opcoes.val() }, function( dados_retornados ){
      //retorne os dados atualizados pela consulta
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="select_comentario">
  <option value="tempo">Mais recente</option>
  <option value="utilidade">Utilidade</option>
  <option value="avaliacao">Avaliação</option>
</select>
```

Claro que na página onde você faz a consulta no banco de dados você tem que  passar os parâmetros de consulta pra query.

Quando o usuário seleciona a opção, os valores da opção são enviados pelo jQuery para a página de consulta e a página de consulta ordena:

```html
<?php
//nao esquecer da conexao com o banco de dados :p
$ordernar_por = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ordenar');

if($ordenar_por == 'avaliacao'){
  //selecione e ordene por avaliacao
}else if($ordenar_por == 'utilidade'){
  //selecione e ordene por utilidade
}else{
  //selecione e ordene por data
}
```

Do lado cliente, você pode usar alguma coisa que gere o HTML dinamicamente, porque se não você tem que montar o grid toda vez que for feita uma ordenação pelo select.

Comment: Temos um serial downvoter por aqui!!!

Comment: Dá uma conferida em: [JS, CSS e HTML executáveis no corpo da pergunta ou resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/201)

Comment: Essa parte já consegui, via GET, agora só to com dificuldade para colocar em ordem os comentário que tem mais like

Comment: Você tá armazenando no banco de dados os "likes", certo?! Então ordena na query. Sempre que você passar o parâmetro de pesquisa, você coloca pra ordenar por esse parâmetro. Algo do tipo`SELECT * FROM comentarios ORDER BY '$likes' DESC` pode ser `ASC`. Ordem descendente e ascendente, nessa ordem.

Comment: Sim, fiz umas alteração e consegui :D obrigado!!